why this statment not executing in initstate flutter?
       Future<void> checkUserStatus(context) async {
          final successOrFailure  = await checkUserStatusUseCase(NoParams());
          if(successOrFailure is SuccessResult<bool>){
          emit(state.copyWith(isUserExits: successOrFailure.data));
          logDebug('called');
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomeScreen.route).then((value) => 
            /// this statment not execute in initstate method
            WidgetsBinding.instance.allowFirstFrame());
            this one executing
            logDebug('called 2');
          }
        }

         class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
            @override
          void initState() {
           context.read<SplashViewModelCubit>().checkUserStatus(context);
           super.initState();
         }

why this statment not excecuting ? even i tried also by adding await at Navigator but not working

You need more clarity in your question, also explain what are you expecting to happen

according to the document

Returns a Future that completes to the result value passed to pop when the pushed route is popped off the navigator.

so the statement will be executed after HomeScreen popped
